Electric moped PWM power diode failure
I'm back with my shoddy moped PWM project :)
Here is a link to my previous question which is directly related to what this question will be about: Electric moped PWM MOSFETs failure
Quick recap:

I heavily modified the power circuit in dotted lines since last time, doing my best to consider and apply all the great advice you guys gave me (thanks @Tim Williams and @D.A.S): I paralleled more MOSFETs, soldered them properly, used gate resistors, brought the diode closer to the MOSFETs, paralleled more capacitors and brought them closer to the MOSFETs, everything in an attempt to reduce the inductance of the switching loop as much as possible. I used an intermediate bus bar insulated from the others to manage that (see pictures below).
Here is the parts list:

The MOSFETs are CSD19506KCS - I've used six in parallel
The MOSFETs are driven by one TC4427A - the driver is supplied by a separate 12 V battery and fed a PWM signal at about 2 kHz from a TLC555
Each MOSFET gate has a 10 Ω gate resistor
The motor is an LEM-130 - a brushed DC motor with a peak current of ~100 A
The motor is supplied with two lead-acid car batteries in series for a total of 24 V supply
The diode is a VS-100BGQ10 100 A 100 V Schottky diode
The capacitors are AISHI ERZ1HM102L25OT 1000 µF 50 V 3 A ripple current - I've used ten in parallel

Here are photos of the current circuit construction:

Drain bus bar with the six MOSFETs soldered on it

Drain bus bar mounted on heatsink

Final construction seen from above


Seen from below

I mounted everything and took my bike for a spin yet again, and after ten seconds of driving the diode burst into flames. This took me aback as the diode was the component I least expected to fail. This highlights yet another gap in my knowledge.
Here are my observations during testing:

Just as before, when powering up the control and power circuits, the 2 kHz ringing could be heard, but significantly louder this time
What surprised me is that even after powering off the power circuit, the ringing could still be heard for a minute or so, decreasing slowly in intensity, whereas in the previous iterations of the circuit it stopped instantly
When actually driving the bike, the ringing got very loud and that is when the diode burst into flames
Nothing was hot, apart from the diode :)

Post-failure testing on the bench:

Diode failed as a short
Nothing else was damaged, MOSFETs held up very well and the control circuit is still alive

My analysis:
This immediately brought back to my mind what user @D.A.S told me in the previous question, that "low Rdson and low ESR will cause high Q LC ringing unless properly damped".
So my idea is that the diode died of voltage breakdown from the ringing. But the diode is rated for 100 V; does that mean the ringing got to 100 V? That seems insane to me.
I also read online that diodes can die from reverse recovery breakdown in hard-switching applications. The diode I'm using is rated for ~500 ns recovery time which seems very slow when compared to other Schottky rectifiers with ~50 ns recovery times.
What do you think about this diode failure?
Was it caused by high voltage ringing or reverse recovery breakdown? Or are both related in a way I don't yet understand?
Would a RC snubber across the diode be a good idea? If it is, how would you size it?
Should I use a diode with faster recovery time? Would paralleling two diodes be useful in this case?
What do you think about my current layout?
Thank you again for the time you will spend analyzing my new failure.
I hope to learn a lot from you guys again.
Have a great day
EDIT :
I've ran a simulation with as many non-ideal ESL and ESR as I could find and here is what I get :

We have 100 V peaks across the MOSFETs (green), 60 V across the diode (blue) and ~200 A going through the diode (red) for 50% PWM.

By adding a RC snubber across the diode (10 ohms, 1 µF) and a RCD (100 ohms, 10 µF and a rectifier) snubber across the MOSFETs, the voltage peaks are reduced to 35 V.

Possibly damaged from soldering? Take a look at the solder time/temp profile from the datasheet and the absolute max solder temperature; those devices aren't really made to go on busbars like that.

Yes, that's something I thought about, because I soldered everything using a small butane torch, and they specify in the datasheet screw mounting only ... Do you think this would lead to a short failure as this one ?

I think it's at least suspect. Unfortunately, while I have destroyed many devices, I have managed to remain mostly ignorant of their failure modes.

Butane flame is around 2000°C. That's way, way over any normal soldering temp. You could probably melt silicon with that.

The way I proceeded for soldering was as follow : I heated the bar from the backside using the torch until I could melt a small puddle of solder on the front side, put the device on the puddle, keep heating until I can see solder has properly wet everything and then immediately cover with a soaking wet towel to remove heat as quickly as possible. I did this for the mosfets and they held up well. In terms of temperature I would say it stayed at solder melting temperature or slightly above for 5 seconds max

Vishay soldering guidelines are here: https://www.vishay.com/docs/88854/solderingprocess.pdf I think that even with your precautions you probably did damage the diode. Max temperature regardless of time looks to be around 250C for your package and I doubt you stayed below this, even with your precautions. The tab's got a screw hole; use it!

Thanks for your answers ; yes, I'm gonna give it another try screwing it on. I still would've liked to know if ringing is an issue in my layout, I'll try a bounty to see if some people could help me in that regard

I don't agree with the diode location - I would put it as close as possible to the motor. Ringing over 100V is certainly possible with your design - your layout is flying leads all over. You need to characterize the nature of the ringing before you can treat it. After you deal with the diode problem, I see other problems that will likely rise.

@MOSFET - Thank you for your answer ; in previous iterations, I actually put the diode right across the motor leads (with a snubber), but I've been told in a previous question to put the diode as close as possible to the MOSFETs in order to make a switching loop as tight as possible. What do you mean by "flying leads all over" ? Still too much inductance in the layout ? What other problems will rise after moving the diode ? Won't the switching loop be larger then and voltage spikes even greater ?

Do not use butane torches for soldering circuits like this. Get a proper 60W temp-controlled iron. You will keep destroying stuff until then. That was an important detail.

Is this just a bench-top test device, or are you really planning to take an actual ride with this sort of mechanical construction? I strongly doubt this bunch of capacitors just hanging there in the air on their long leads is going to survive all the vibrations and shocks. Automotive in general is pretty much the nastiest environment you can find for electronics.

It's just me doing stupid stuff in the backyard, and this is pretty much the project that had me learn everything I know about electronics, so no, it's not clean and tight like a Tesla


What do you think about this diode failure ?

It's likely that you have overtemped the diode in some way, either in installation or when you are dissipating the back EMF into the motor.
Also you need to know if the motor is going beyond the the voltage, it would be good if you could test it with an oscilloscope or DMM attached to see if it goes beyond the voltage of the diode. (you can get DMM with a min max function to see what the voltage is or use a portable oscilloscope to monitor the voltage while testing it on the bike)
If it's not over volatge then it's probably over current, try putting a fuse in series with the diode (like a 100A fuse) If the fuse blows then paralleling diodes would be good.

Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question by adding some simulations with and without snubbers. Without snubbers I think that, indeed, the voltage spikes are way too high and the 200 A going through the diode requires paralleling at least two of them. What do you think ?

I think that's good, it's likely that you need to parallel your diodes, make sure you also put in resistance and inductance of the bus bars and other conductors in the simulation. You can estimate them with conductor calculators

Thank you for your input; I'll parallel two diodes, add snubbers and greatly increase the gear ratio on the mechanical side so that the motor draws less current and has more torque.

Do put more diodes in parallel. Do snub the diodes and consider snubbing the MOSFETs. Also get some MLC caps like say 10 uF 50 V in parallel with the supply rail to help at the high frequencies where the electros do not perform well.

Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question by adding some simulations with and without snubbers, what do you think about the snubber circuits I used and the component values ? With ~200 A going through the diode, paralleling at least two of them seems mandatory.
